# Bootstrap time picker not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a JS error on line 752 of `bootstrap-datetimepicker.js`.
It also happens when I click the Time button.

The error is:

```
 TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function(evaluating'expanded.collapse('hide')')
```

Why does this happen? How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you provide us some code?

Comment: and also provide the timepicker & bootstrap.js version

Answer (score 1):

According to a [issue on github](https://github.com/TrevorS/bootstrap3-datetimepicker-rails/issues/6#issuecomment-44133601), this error occures when you do not include the `bootstrap.js` file, because `collapse` is defined in it.

Make sure you include the corresponding version:

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```